# FIND - how do you use -exec {} +?

Tags: find

I'm learning the command `find`, and have a search that works, using `-exec cp {} \;`.

THANK YOU FOR THE REPLIES.  THIS IS MY EDITED QUESTION:
(I hope this meets the formatting conventions.)

Below, I copied (with an extra line between command sets for legibility) a sequence of commands that show what I'm doing.

To summarize:

1) I started with a directory structure of test/testsub1/testsub2, with 3 files in test/ and 3 files in test/testsub1/; none in test/testsub1/testsub2/.

2) I created 10000 files named filesub2-xxxxx in test/testsub1/testsub2/, and confirmed their existence with the next `ls` command.

3) I used the `find` command to locate the 10000 files and used the `-exec cp`{}`test/ \;` expression to copy them to test/.  Confirmation with the next `ls` command.

4) I removed the 10000 copied files from test/.  Confirmation with the next `ls` command.

5) Then I tried to use the exact same `find` command, except replacing the `;` with a `+`, with and without quoting and backslash, none of which 
worked.  (The last version addresses the suggestion below that '{}' should be in last position.)

Hence, my question.

```
mr@dpobx:~$ ls -R test/
test/:
file1
file2
file3
testsub1

test/testsub1:
filesub1
filesub2
filesub3
testsub2

test/testsub1/testsub2:

mr@dpobx:~$ touch test/testsub1/testsub2/filesub2-{00001..10000}

mr@dpobx:~$ ls test/testsub1/testsub2/ | wc -l
10000

mr@dpobx:~$ time find test/ -iname "*sub2-*" -exec cp '{}' test/ \;

real    0m8.397s
user    0m6.484s
sys 0m1.943s

mr@dpobx:~$ ls test/ | wc -l
10004

mr@dpobx:~$ rm -f test/filesub2-*

mr@dpobx:~$ ls test/ | wc -l
4

mr@dpobx:~$ time find test/ -iname "*sub2-*" -exec cp '{}' test/ \+
find: missing argument to `-exec'

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s

mr@dpobx:~$ time find test/ -iname "*sub2-*" -exec cp '{}' test/ '+'
find: missing argument to `-exec'

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.004s

mr@dpobx:~$ time find test/ -iname "*sub2-*" -exec cp '{}' test/ +
find: missing argument to `-exec'

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s

mr@dpobx:~$ time find test/ -iname "*sub2-*" -exec cp test/ '{}' \+
cp: target 'test/testsub1/testsub2/filesub2-07915' is not a directory
cp: target 'test/testsub1/testsub2/filesub2-05333' is not a directory
cp: target 'test/testsub1/testsub2/filesub2-07548' is not a directory

real    0m0.033s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.015s

mr@dpobx:~$
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide the code you tried (the one you think should work ?)

Comment: Well, `cp` needs two arguments, a source and a target. You only provide one, `{}`, the file just found, but you don't provide a target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `-exec ... +`, the  `{}` must **always** be in the last position.

See the syntax in `man find`:

> `-exec command {} +`

So this does not work:

```
find . -exec cp {} my/target/ +
```

You need to use the third form of `cp` and use of the `-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY` option:

```
cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE
```

So, this should work:

```
find . -exec cp -t my/target/ {} +
```

---

Btw: the same applies to `find -exec` with `mv`.

Comment: '@pLumo - you are absolutely right, thank you!  I was reminded of this question when learning about xargs invoking a shell in order to avoid a similar problem with mv. That opened my eyes to what it means "must be in last position", and why my construction did not achieve that.  BTW: {} + is roughly 30x faster than {} ;!